# discord.js v14 | canvas module is not loading my image

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, canvas, discord.js

I am trying to load my background to manipulate it with canvas but i keep getting this error: `ENOENT, No such file or directory 'C:\Users\grkmd\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Lum\images\test.png'`

I checked the path a several thousand times, its true. I also tried using JPG image instead of PNG but still same error.

**my code:**

```js
    const path = require('path');
    const { MessageAttachment } = require('discord.js');
    const { createCanvas, loadImage } = require('canvas');

    const applyText = (canvas, text) => {
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const fontSize = 70;

    do {
      context.font = `${fontSize -= 10}px sans-serif`;
    } while (context.measureText(text).width > canvas.width - 300);

      return context.font;
    };

    var canvas = createCanvas(700, 250);
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var backgroundImage = path.join(__dirname, '../../', 'images', 'test.png')
    console.log(backgroundImage)
    var background = await loadImage(backgroundImage);

    context.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    context.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var text = 'Deneme';
    var textFont = applyText(canvas, text);
    context.font = textFont;
    context.fillStyle = '#000000';
    context.textAlign = 'center';
    context.textBaseline = 'middle';
    context.fillText(text, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(125, 125, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.closePath();
    context.clip();

    var avatar = await loadImage(message.author.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png' }));
    context.drawImage(avatar, 25, 25, 200, 200);

    var finalImage = new MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'image.png');
    message.channel.send({ files: [finalImage] });
```

[image: Path and file's image]

[image: Console output when i run the code]

Comment: can you attach an image of the file directory?

Comment: I added it to bottom.

Comment: maybe I'm misreading your path, but it seems to include "Bu bilgisayar" but that's not in your generated path.  is this the issue?  if not, you should try console.log(path) and echo out what you're loading...

Comment: Nope, as i said before the path is 100% correct. I did what you suggest anyway and I added the console output to the post, as you can see it still says theres no file but just before the error message you can see loaded files path.

Comment: Also are you sure that its a png and not jpg or some other file format?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I also tried to use JPG image but didnt work, it gave the same error.